# Total users from serialized id field

Tags: php

I need a little help to get **how many users are associated with a specific company** from a serialized id field.

```
TABLE_USER
user_id
user_name
user_companies <- Serialized id field
```

If I have a INT field I can get value in this way:

```
 SELECT * FROM table_user WHERE user_companies = 1
```

But, how to get total users from serialized field?
Any example would be appreciated

TKS all

Comment: You REALLY don't want to do this. Scrap the database and use a normalized data structure. Or if you can't do that, you'll have to do this in PHP

Comment: @Eat, Sure, i have to do this in PHP, but i'm like to have an example :-)

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at PHP's `unserialize()` function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: @Abra, get total number of user associated to company 1: In user company i have stored a company_id array

Comment: Example: select * from table_user WHERE (an item in my serialized field) = '1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the way to use a database.  Ideally you should have a joined table with users and companies. It wouldn't be that difficult to run one script that selects, unserializes and inserts into a new table that you can join.  But assuming that's how it is you have to do it in PHP:

```
// SELECT * FROM table_user

$company_id = 1;

while($row = your_fetch_array()) {
    if(in_array($company_id, unserialize($row['user_companies'])) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
}
```

To get the unserialized companies in the result array:

```
while($row = your_fetch_array()) {
    $companies = unserialize($row['user_companies']);

    if(in_array($company_id, $companies) {
        $results[] = array_merge($row, array('user_companies' => $companies));
    }
}
```

You don't mention your database or API, so query and fetch as you normally would.

If you use JSON (still not recommended) then you may get some mileage out of [MySQL JSON Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html).